# The name 'xxx' does not exist in the current context (are you missing a reference to assembly)

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

I have installed Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp & Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting (Version 3.3.1) packages in the .Net Core 2.2 Console Application and also I have developed the codes below :

```
SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
    public class MyGlobals
    {
        public int Age {get; set;} = 21;
    }
");

var references = new List<MetadataReference>
{
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
};

var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("DynamicAssembly")
    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree)
    .AddReferences(references);

Type globalsType = null;
Assembly assembly = null;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var compileResult = compilation.Emit(memoryStream);
    assembly = Assembly.Load(memoryStream.GetBuffer());

    if (compileResult.Success)
    {
        globalsType = assembly.GetType("MyGlobals");
    }
}
var globals = Activator.CreateInstance(globalsType);
var validationResult = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>("Age == 21", globals: globals);
```

The globals object is created but the expression is not evaluated and the following exception is throwed by CSharpScript :

> The name 'Age' does not exist in the current context (are you missing a reference to assembly 'DynamicAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'?)'

Is there a setting I missed?

Comment: I think the problem might be `globals` variable is of type object. You probably need to cast it to `MyGlobals` type.

Comment: I think there's still an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6101)...

Comment: @dropoutcoder How can I change the globals variable type to a dynamic class which generated by SyntaxTree ?!

Comment: you may try `dynamic globals = Activator.CreateInstance(globalsType);`

Comment: Why would that make a difference, @dropoutcoder?

Comment: @dropoutcoder, The "dynamic globals" doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get an error is the absence of reference to DynamicAssembly you just created. To fix this you may pass `ScriptOptions` to `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>()` call. The following code runs well for me.

```
SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(@"
public class MyGlobals
{
    public int Age {get; set;} = 21;
}
");

var references = new List<MetadataReference>
{
    MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location)
};

var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("DynamicAssembly")
    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree)
    .AddReferences(references);

Type globalsType = null;
Assembly assembly = null;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var compileResult = compilation.Emit(memoryStream);
    var buffer = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
    File.WriteAllBytes("DynamicAssembly.dll", buffer);
    assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.GetFullPath("DynamicAssembly.dll"));

    if (compileResult.Success)
    {
        globalsType = assembly.GetType("MyGlobals");
    }
}

var globals = Activator.CreateInstance(globalsType);
var options = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences("DynamicAssembly.dll");

var validationResult = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>(
    "Age == 21",
    globals: globals,
    options: options
);
Console.WriteLine(await validationResult);
```

Comment: It throws an exception like this : System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. ([A]MyGlobals cannot be cast to [B]MyGlobals. Type A originates from 'DynamicAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location

Comment: @MohsenAlikhani make sure you load DynamicAssembly from saved assembly like this `assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Path.GetFullPath("DynamicAssembly.dll"))`.
In other words assembly from which you load `MyGlobals` type must located at same path as you provide in `ScriptOptions`.